# Programmatically set the NLog target attributes

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using [NLog Azure Storage Logger](https://github.com/heemskerkerik/NLog.AzureAppendBlob). My config is as below,
I don't want to put the storage key in the target. Instead, I will use it from app settings so that I can set the Azure website "Application Settings" in the deployment environment. How can I programmatically set the `connectionString` for this target?

```
 <nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"
   xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
```

```
<target type="AzureAppendBlob"
           name="azure"
           layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${message}"
           connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mylogs;AccountKey=xxxoxxx=="
           container="myappcontainer"
           blobName="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
```

Looking for something like,

```
public class NLogService: IMyLogService
{
   ....

    public NLogService()
    {
        Logger azureLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("AzureAppendBlob");
        AzureAppendBlobTarget t = dbLogger.????;
        t.ConnectionString = "..."; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way:

```
var azureBlobTarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<AzureAppendBlobTarget>("azure");
azureBlobTarget.ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mylogs;AccountKey=xxx";
```

This also works if NLog is configured with a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do it,

```
    public NLogService()
    {
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        var azureBlobTarget = new AzureAppendBlobTarget();
        config.AddTarget("azureAppender", azureBlobTarget);

        azureBlobTarget.BlobName = "${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log";  
        azureBlobTarget.ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mylogs;AccountKey=xxx";
        azureBlobTarget.Container = "myapp";
        azureBlobTarget.Layout = @"${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} - ${message}";            

        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, azureBlobTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        // Step 5. Activate the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }
```